# update user profile in silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0, wcf-ria-services

i create a user profile page in  silverlight , i use wcfria in my project
i write these code but doesnt change in my database.
how can i implement this page ?
my code is :

```
//domain service


        public void EditUser(tblUser user,long id)
        {
            var query=(mydb.tblUsers.Where(u=>u.user_id==id).Select(u=>u)).Single();
            try
            {
                query.fname = user.fname;
                query.lname = user.lname;
                query.email = user.email;
                query.cnum = user.cnum;
                query.address = user.address;
                query.url = user.url;
                mydb.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch
            {
                return;
            }
        }


    //code behind :
     ctx.EditUser(user, id);
     ctx.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if your try-catch is catching something? Actually, what are you expecting to change? You seem to be locating a user by ID and then setting the fields to the value they already have ...

Comment: @Mashton : i insert new values in the instance of tbluser (user) and then send this table and the id of this user EditUser. the input values are textboxes that user fill them.

Comment: Yeah sorry I was being dumb. Misread the tblUser parameter ... but then that's what happens when you name c# classes like sql table names!